# Write Objective-C class from scratch

Tags: objective-c

I'd like to write an Objective-C class without Cocoa or GNU's `Object.h` (for educational purposes). I dug around the net and it seems to me that quite a lot of stuff that one would expect to "come with the language", such as classes and message sending are actually defined in files written by third parties, such as `objc-runtime.h`.

Is there any documentation about what is *really* pure Objective-C and what is part of the runtime / frameworks? And what functionality do I have to implement to get a working environment without using any third-party code such as `Object.h` or `objc-runtime.h` (note again that this is for educational purposes, not for production code)?

Thanks for any insight!

Comment: Read this [resource](http://cocoasamurai.blogspot.com/2010/01/understanding-objective-c-runtime.html) from Colin Wheeler. It's not about creating a custom class but how NSObject obfuscates the process of tying our classes to the runtime.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Really, the only thing you *must* take care of yourself if you don't inherit from `NSObject` is object creation and destruction; methods otherwise behave the same way regardless of their parent class. Features like KVC and memory management are features of OpenStep/Cocoa, but not required as part of the language.

Here's a class from scratch:

```
@interface MyClass { // note the lack of a superclass here
    @private Class isa;
}
+ (MyClass *)create;
- (void)destroy;

- (int)randomNumber;
@end


@implementation MyClass
+ (MyClass *)create {
    return class_createInstance(self, 0);
}

- (void)destroy {
    object_dispose(self);
}

- (int)randomNumber {
    return rand();
}
@end
```

And here's how it could be used:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    MyClass *foo = [MyClass create];
    if (foo) {
        printf("random! %i\n", [foo randomNumber]);
        [foo destroy];
    }
}
```

**Edit:** If you don't even want to use `class_createInstance()` and `object_dispose()`, you'll have to implement equivalents manually, as well as an equivalent of `class_getInstanceSize()` so you know how much memory an object occupies. But even if you manage that, don't think you've escaped the Objective-C runtime! Message dispatch is still entirely built on the C functions in the runtime, and Objective-C syntax is transformed into calls to those functions during compilation.

Comment: Your code requires including `objc-runtime.h` (or some other header file) that defines `class_createInstance` and `object_dispose`. I don't want to include anything I haven't written myself.

Comment: You need at least those two functions in order to create an Objective-C class that can be instantiated. The rest is optional.

Comment: @Jonathan Grynspan: But those methods have to be declared and implemented somewhere, don't they?

Comment: So do `objc_msgSend()` and a dozen other C functions in the runtime.

Comment: @Jonathan Grynspan: Well, that's exactly what I want to find out: what do I have to implement in order to get a working Objective-C environment.

Comment: So you want to build your own Objective-C runtime and Objective-C compiler? You'll need your own C compiler as well, since you don't want to use any GCC code... ;)

Comment: you need to add `Class is_a` as an iVar. Otherwise calling methods on the class will crash horribly.

Comment: @Jonathan Grynspan: Okay, I accept I won't rewrite the objc runtime. I'm going to accept your answer since it's the closest thing to what I originally wanted.

Answer (score 2):

Matt Gallagher wrote a really [cool post](http://cocoawithlove.com/2010/09/minimalist-cocoa-programming.html) on writing a bare-bones Cocoa program.  Since Objective-C is a superset of C, you can just do:

```
echo "int main(){return 0;}" | gcc -x objective-c -; ./a.out ; echo $?
```

Anyways, you probably would get a lot out of reading his post.

Comment: All his sample programs (except the one you posted) use code written by third parties (namely `Object.h` and `objc-runtime.h`) that I do not want to use.

Answer (score 1):

As far as avoiding the framework and creating your own base object goes, all you need to do is make sure that the first iVar is declared `Class is_a` and you could probably have a reasonable stab at replicating NSObject is by passing through to the runtime functions.

As far as avoiding the runtime library AND the framework goes, that's not really possible. Objective C (or at least, the bits that aren't just C) is a dynamic language. So pretty much everything it does that C doesn't do is handled by the runtime library.

It might be possible to build your own classes and objects using the 32bit runtime and the deprecated API, which doesn't abstract away the layout of classes, protocols, etc. to the extent that the modern runtime does (I've only really poked around with the modern runtime)

Perhaps you could create classes, add methods and allocate instances and by setting values in class_t structs and then using malloc() to allocate, although even then, you'd still be implicitly using the runtime function objc_msgSend every time you used the `[obj selector]` syntax -- unless you want to implement that as well, in which case you've just reimplemented the language yourself. The 'pure core' of the language you're looking for *just is* the runtime.

Comment: Ah, but he wants to know how to do it without using any runtime functions. ;p

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of class, without using class_createInstance or object_dispose, or any other Objective-C Runtime (at least we don't call them directly).

```
#import <objc/objc.h>
#import <stdio.h>
#import <stdlib.h>
#import <string.h>

static Class __scratchClass = NULL;

@interface Scratch {
  Class isa;
  char *name;
}
+ (id) initialize;
+ (Scratch*) new:(const char*)strName;
- (void) sayHello;
- (void) destroy;
@end

@implementation Scratch

+ (id) initialize { 
  __scratchClass = self;
  return self;
}

+ (Scratch*) new:(const char*) strName {
  Scratch* pObj = (Scratch*)malloc(sizeof(Scratch));
  if (!pObj) return NULL;
  memset(pObj, 0, sizeof(Scratch));
  pObj->isa = __scratchClass;
  pObj->name = (char*)malloc(strlen(strName)+1);
  strcpy(pObj->name, strName);
  return pObj;
}

- (void) sayHello {
  printf("Hello, World!\nThis is Scratch (%s)...\n", name);
}

- (void) destroy {
  if (name) {
     free(name);
     name = NULL;
  }
  free(self);
}

@end

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  Scratch* ps = [Scratch new:argv[0]];
  [ps sayHello];
  [ps destroy];
  return 0;
}
```

Compile the code with (assuming you save it as 'test1.m'):

**gcc -o test1 test1.m -lobjc**